# Updating routing graph based on GIS changes in DB

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po, osm2pgsql

I am using Osm2PO for route finding which reads a graph file created from a pbf file downloaded from OpenStreetMap.

I have my own GIS database where updates may be applied to the data. I would like Osm2PO to be able to generate a graph based on this DB.

Does anyone know how I can generate a osm pbf file from a database created using Osm2Pgsql? I have tried using Osmosis with commands like:

```
osmosis --read-pgsql host="localhost" database="gis" user="username" --write-pbf file="OSMDump"
```

but it gives an error saying Task 2-write-pbf does not support data provided by default pipe stored at level 1 in the default pipe stack.

Thanks

Relations table schame

```
Table "public.planet_osm_rels"
 Column  |   Type   | Modifiers 
---------+----------+-----------
 id      | bigint   | not null
 way_off | smallint | 
 rel_off | smallint | 
 parts   | bigint[] | 
 members | text[]   | 
 tags    | text[]   | 
 pending | boolean  | not null
```

Code:
Here are the classes (I'll leave out the getters/setters):
Node class:

```
private long id;
private int lat;
private int lon;
private String[] tags;
```

Way class:

```
private long id;
private Long[] nodes;
private String[] tags;
```

Relation:

```
private long id;
private String[] members;
private String[] tags;
```

parse method (gets data from DB and stores in the collections):

```
ArrayList<Node> nodes = getNodes();
ArrayList<Way> ways = getWays();
ArrayList<Relation> relations = getRelations();

// Process all nodes
for(Node n : nodes) {
    this.gisHandler.onNode(n.getId(), n.getLat(), n.getLon());
    if(n.getTags() !=null) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n.getTags().length-1; i+=2) {
            this.gisHandler.onNodeTag(n.getTags()[i], n.getTags()[i+1]);
        }   
    }
    this.gisHandler.onNodeComplete();
    this.gisHandler.closeNodeProcessing();
}


// Process all ways
for(Way w : ways) {
    this.gisHandler.onWay(w.getId());
    // Node refs
    for(Long l : w.getNodes()) {
        this.gisHandler.onWayNdRef(l);  
    }
    // Node tags
    if(w.getTags() != null) {
        for(int i = 0; i < w.getTags().length-1; i+=2) {
            this.gisHandler.onNodeTag(w.getTags()[i], w.getTags()[i+1]);
        }
    }
    this.gisHandler.onWayComplete();
    this.gisHandler.closeWayProcessing();
}

// Process all Relations
for(Relation rel : relations) {
    this.gisHandler.onRelation(rel.getId());
    for(int i = 0; i < rel.getMembers().length-1; i+=2) {
        this.gisHandler.onRelationMember("relation", rel.getId(), "multipolygon");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rel.getTags().length-1; i+=2) {
        this.gisHandler.onNodeTag(rel.getTags()[i], rel.getTags()[i+1]);
    }
    this.gisHandler.onRelationComplete();
    this.gisHandler.closeRelationProcessing();
}
```

Log output

```
ESTABLISHED CONNETION TO GIS DB
INFO   460,001 of 460,001 nodes extracted - 782M
INFO   33,582 of 66,118 ways extracted - 796M
INFO   43 of 827 relations extracted - 796M
INFO   Tiler finished at Mon Mar 04 16:16:42 GMT 2013
INFO   Starting Joiner at Mon Mar 04 16:16:42 GMT 2013
INFO   Caching relations from tr_raw.2po - 864M
INFO   0 of 43 relations cached - 864M
INFO   460,001 of 460,001 nodes cached (n034-e145) - 853M
INFO   33,582 of 33,582 ways read, 33,582 written
       Total 33,582 tiled, 0 shared
INFO   Joiner finished at Mon Mar 04 16:16:43 GMT 2013
INFO   Starting Segmenter at Mon Mar 04 16:16:43 GMT 2013
INFO   0 of 0 nodes cached (shared) - 863M
INFO   175,929 of 222,327 nodes cached (n034-e145) - 830M
INFO   33,582 ways analyzed, 67,881 segments created (n034-e145) - 798M
INFO   55,065 vertices of 175,929 written - 853M
INFO   0 ways analyzed, 0 segments created (shared) - 853M
INFO   0 vertices of 0 written - 853M
INFO   Segmenter finished at Mon Mar 04 16:16:43 GMT 2013
INFO   Starting GraphBuilder at Mon Mar 04 16:16:43 GMT 2013
INFO   Transforming Ways - 853M
INFO   33,582 Ways read, 135,764 Edges cached - 817M  
INFO   Transforming Vertices - 817M
INFO   55,065 Vertices read, 0 Restrictions cached - 814M
INFO   Finding SourceVertex EntryPoints - 814M
INFO   135,764 Edges analyzed
INFO   Creating NoTurnBits - 804M
INFO   135,764 Edges analyzed, 0 Crossings checked
INFO   Writing GraphFile
       gis_2po.gph - 804M
INFO   55,065 entries written     
INFO   135,764 edges written
INFO   GraphBuilder finished at Mon Mar 04 16:16:45 GMT 2013
INFO   Starting PostProccessor at Mon Mar 04 16:16:45 GMT 2013
       [de.cm.osm2po.converter.PgRoutingWriter]
INFO   Creating sql file gis/gis_2po_4pgr.sql
INFO   67,881 Segments written.
INFO   commandline template:
       psql -U [username] -d [dbname] -q -f "/home/sam/src/osm2po/gis/gis_2po_4pgr.sql"
INFO   PostProcessor finished at Mon Mar 04 16:16:46 GMT 2013
INFO   Loading Graph File
       /home/sam/src/osm2po/gis/gis_2po.gph
INFO   Created with Version 4.6.9.4
INFO   Loading SourceVertex-EntryPoints
INFO   55,065 Vertices loaded. - 863M
INFO   Memory for 135,764 edges reserved. - 862M
INFO   135,764 Edges loaded. - 861M
INFO   55,065 Classes loaded. - 861M  
INFO   Memory for 55,065 coords reserved. - 861M
INFO   55,065 Coords loaded.   
INFO   Graph is in memory - 859M free
INFO   Services started. Waiting for requests at
       http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService
```

Answer (score 1):

Why the detour via pbf? osm2po allows you to write your own Reader and to inject it into the processing chain. All you need is a Java-Class which implements `OsmParser`.

```
@Override
public void open(InputStream inputStream,
        OsmParserHandler osmParserHandler, Config config) {
    this.handler = osmParserHandler;
    this.log = config.getLog();
    // inputStream is not needed, open your DB here instead.
    // db-params can be set via config
}

@Override
public void close() {
    // close your db here.
}

@Override
public void parse() {
    // Read your table here and call back

    // 1) All Nodes first
    this.handler.onNode(long id, double lat, double lon);
    this.handler.onNodeTag(String key, String value);
    this.handler.onNodeComplete();
    this.handler.closeNodeProcessing();

    // 2) Then all Ways
    this.handler.onWay(long id);
    this.handler.onWayNdRef(long ndRefId);
    this.handler.onWayTag(String key, String value);
    this.handler.onWayComplete();
    this.handler.closeWayProcessing();

    // 3) Finally all Relations
    this.handler.onRelation(long id);
    this.handler.onRelationMember(String type, long ref, String role);
    this.handler.onRelationTag(String key, String value);
    this.handler.onRelationComplete();
    this.handler.closeRelationProcessing();
}
```

Comment: Do I need to implement my own OsmParserHandler?

Comment: No. The OsmParser is the key interface which I use to implement different readers for e.g pbf, o5m, plain xml, etc.

Comment: In order to trigger it and to chain it into the default mechanism, you must pass an input file (though a db does not need one) Have look into the config where each file extension is associated with a special parser. So associate sth. like *.db with your parser implementation. One idea would be to put all your connection parameters in there instead of declaring them in the osm2po.config.

Comment: Hi, Ok so I have created most of the parser class although I am stuck at the `this.handler.onRelationMember(String type, long ref, String role);`

what is the ref variable here? I'll post my relations table schema in the original post

Comment: This corresponds to a native OSM-relation. Each member of a relation references either a node, a way or another relation. So for the type parameter pass "node", "way" or "relation". An OSM-role can be everything, even self-invented stuff. The ref-parameter is the ID of the element (e.g. ID of the node).

Comment: Hi, sorry for all the questions. I have added the new parser to the `de.cm.osm2po.plugins` folder within osm2po-plugins-src which I extracted.

How do I recreate the plugins jar file so that I can execute the new parser? I have tried `jar cf osm2po-plugins-4.6.9 *` within the src folder but all the files within the jar are just .java files

Comment: It's easy. Firstly, don't touch the original plugins.jar. I assume you are using Eclipse, so just export your implementation as jar. Copy the created jar to the plugins folder. That's all (osm2po uses its own classloader so your jar will be automatically included by osm2po). Secondly associate your reader with a file extension in the osm2po.config or on the commandline. Sth. like osmParser.myext=my.ImplClazz. Actually you need a file to trigger it. The file itself may be empty.

Comment: Thanks, osm2po now picks it up. It gives me debug statements like `INFO   421,554 of 421,554 nodes extracted - 567M
DEBUG  Setting Tile n034-e145 to not relevant. Number of nodes 1 < 100` when processing the nodes but when processing ways and relations I get only get statements like `INFO   0 of 43,144 ways extracted - 659M`. It always says `0 of ...`.

When it is finished processing it says that there are 0 ways or relations and `0 vertices of 0 written`. I'll post my code in the original post.

Comment: Please excuse, that's my fault. I did not explain it exactly. The "this.gisHandler.closeXxxProssing()" methods should be called after the loop and not inside.

Comment: The nodes seem to extract now but 0 ways and relations were extracted. Here is part of the output:  `INFO   460,001 of 460,001 nodes extracted - 765M
INFO   0 of 66,118 ways extracted - 765M
INFO   0 of 827 relations extracted - 765M`

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you pass to `this.gisHandler.onNodeTag(w.getTags()[i], w.getTags()[i+1]);` Can you give me a short dump?

Comment: oops! why do you call onNodeTag() anyway? For ways use onWayTag()

Comment: That was a copy paste mistake :(. I changed that and it seems to generate a graph and SQL file. The log reports ` 33,582 of 66,118 ways extracted - 792M
INFO   43 of 827 relations extracted - 792M` so they don't all seem to be being read. Also, the resulting graph file is not routeable. The Osm2Po service doesn't provide any routes nor does the progam I am using the graph file in.
In your previous post, I use `i` for the key and `i+1` for the value.

Comment: The values for n-of-m extracted are ok. Here the osm2po-TagResolvers which act like filters came into play. I assume your 43 relations are TurnRestrictions. Ok, you said, the graph is not routable. I think this is a data-problem now. Can you ensure, that you've passed the same values / ids / refIds as if they were fetched from an osm.xml? Most important: The Node-IDs and Way-IDRefs MUST match. Can you give me some more log-data? What did the Joiner and Segmenter (most important) say?

Comment: Anyway, the created sql file contains almost the same data as the graph file. Just import it into your db and visualize it with QuantumGIS. You can even analyze the underlying data in this great program.

Comment: Hi, I added the log output to the original post. I added a screenshot of eclipse using the OsmDebugParserHandler just to show an example of the type of values I get for a way. I accidentally added this to your post instead of mine.

When I loaded the table into QuantumGIS it is just blank so there is something definitely wrong there.

Comment: @sam, judging from the large amounts of output you have been trying to post and the length of this comment thread, it's time that you went into chat to continue this conversation: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7755/sam-and-carsten.

Comment: Last comment here (promised). Sam, please send me an email.